# Forward request headers to next microservice using Jaeger in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, trace, zipkin, jaeger

I have two basic Springboot microservices and I am using Jaeger. Lets say two services are `foo` and `bar`. I am able to send `User-Agent` header from foo to bar service using Tracing Baggage property.

From `foo` service, I will be calling `bar` service using `localhost:port` as of now.

The users will also send an `x-api-key` header in the request. This header is not being forward from `foo` to `bar` service.

This is my code snippet,

```
public ResponseEntity<String> fooService(@RequestHeader("User-Agent") String userAgent, @RequestHeader(value="x-api-key", required = false) String apikeyHeader) {
        try {
            /**
             * Set baggage
             */
            tracer.activeSpan().setBaggageItem("user-agent", userAgent);

            if (apikeyHeader != null && !apikeyHeader.isEmpty()) {
                tracer.activeSpan().setBaggageItem("x-api-key", apikeyHeader);
            }
```

On the logs of my `bar` service, it is receiving these headers,
`uberctx-user-agent` and `uberctx-x-api-key`

I am not sure why `uber-ctx-*` is appended, I only want `x-api-key` header to be forwarded.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a baggage item is *not* the same as setting an HTTP header. You should use your HTTP client (not shown in your example) to set the HTTP header.

Baggage items might or not be available as individual HTTP headers: it's a detail implementation of the underlying tracer, such as Jaeger's.